# Find user who kicked off a SQL Agent job at runtime

Tags: sql-server-2016, security

I have inherited a breakglass procedure that allows certain users to kick off a SQL Agent job that inflates their privileges on the instance.

It currently sends an email to say that it has been invoked, waits for 4 hours then revokes the privileges, sending an email out to say that it has been revoked.

But I just can't find a way to capture who kicked the Agent job off.

Is there a way that the user id details can be captured or is it always going to take the SQL Agent users details?

Comment: How do they kick off the procedure? Is it a simple `execute <procedure_name>` or is this something that is triggered in an application? Could you be a bit more specific? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be available in the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table under the message column.

We can use some code to extract the text based on the "Executed as user" text:

```
SELECT          [j].[name] AS [JobName],
                CASE
                    WHEN LEFT([h].[message], 17) = 'Executed as user:' THEN
                        SUBSTRING([h].[message], 19, CHARINDEX('.', [h].[message], 1) - 18)
                    WHEN [h].[message] LIKE '%invoked by%' THEN
                        SUBSTRING(
                                     [h].[message],
                                     CHARINDEX('invoked by ', [h].[message]) + 11,
                                     CHARINDEX(
                                                  '.',
                                                  SUBSTRING(
                                                   [h].[message],
                                                   CHARINDEX('invoked by ', [h].[message]) + 11,
                                                   99
                                                   )
                                              ) - 1
                                 )
                    ELSE
                        [h].[message]
                END,
                [h].[message]
FROM            [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]       AS [j]
    INNER JOIN  [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] AS [h]
                ON
                [j].[job_id] = [h].[job_id]
WHERE           [j].[enabled] = 1   --Only Enabled Jobs
ORDER BY        [JobName];
```

Comment: This is where you would find that information.  Assuming that they kick the job off through SSMS or using sp_start_job.

Comment: It's not perfect but the nearest I have seen, thanks George

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT getdate() as [Capture_Date], @@Servername as [Instance_Name], h.run_date as [Run_Date], [j].[name] AS [Job_Name], h.message as [Message_Text], 
    SUBSTRING(Message, 48, (LEN(h.Message) - 229)) as [User_Name]
    FROM            [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]       AS [j]
        INNER JOIN  [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] AS [h]
                    ON [j].[job_id] = [h].[job_id]
    WHERE           [j].[name] = '_DBA; grant sysadmin rights to Developers'
    AND h.message like '%The Job was invoked by%'
```

For anyone Googling the same information, this is my solution.